# jQuery run animation alternatively

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have two animations:

```
$("#div1").animate({scrollTop:$("#div1").width()},1000);
```

this one animates the scroll of the div to the bottom most point.
While the 2nd one,

```
$("#div1").animate({scrollTop:0},1000);
```

animates it back to the top.

Now, I want to run these animations alternatively, like the css animations has the alternate mode. Which means as soon as the first animation finishes the second one starts and second one finishes the first one starts and so forth forever...

Is there any way to do this in jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make them recursive functions which call each other infinitely:

```
function goDown() {
$("#div1").animate({scrollTop:$("#div1").width()},1000,function(){goUp()});
}

function goUp() {
$("#div1").animate({scrollTop:0},1000,function(){goDown()});
}
```

call either function to begin the madness

Comment: Only one problem, seems to fish me, if you actually put this to use(you need to change scrollTop to scrollLeft) is it that one directions animation is faster and other one is slower ? The down one is fast (speed)

Comment: I think you may be overshooting the width with $("#div1").width(). I have heard it goes twice as far as it needs to. If its that part of the animation, just make the faster animation's time 2000 rather than 1000; this is my lazy man's approach.

Comment: Well, that wasn't what I was saying. I mean one way its fast other way its slow.

Comment: Thats what I mean, the faster animation is faster because it is attempting to travel twice as far within 1000 milliseconds. If you give it more time it will travel at the same speed as the other one, hopefully.

Comment: Then both of them should run twice faster, if t runs twice faster default.